# date time comparison in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

i have two time values as give below

```
$row2[0]=00:40:00;
$row1[5]=14:00:00;
$time=14:33:00
$time=$row[1];
```

i am combining $row2[0],$row1[5] like below

```
$secs = strtotime($row2[0])-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($row1[5])+$secs);

$result=14:40:00
```

i use if condition as shown

```
if($row[1]>$row1[5] && $row[1]<$result)
{
$message=array("status"=>$result);
}
else
{
$message=array("status"=>'');
}
```

but  i  get `"status"=>""` its not correct

i want to get `"status"=>"14:40:00"`

please help us for getting correct out put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to define `$row[1]` anywhere, so it is treated as `NULL`, which as an integer is `0`, which cannot be greater than the time you have given in `$row1[5]`.

Try using less ambiguous variable names, it might make it easier to spot problems like this.

Personally I don't see why that `if` is there at all, just remove it and the `else` block, leaving just `$message = array("status"=>$result);`.

Answer (score 1):

is this real oder pseudo code ?
because

```
$row2[0]=00:40:00;
```

is not real php code !

```
$row2[0] = 00:40:00; // $row2[0] would be 0, because you are assigning an integer
$row2[0] = "00:40:00"; // $row2[0] would be "00:40:00", but as a string (!)
```

i would always work with timestamps btw.

Answer (score 0):

I go with Panique on his answer, I want to add also:

You declared two vars:

```
$row2[0]=00:40:00;
$row1[5]=14:00:00;
```

But you called different array elements in the if

```
if($row[1]>$row1[5] && $row[1]<$result)
```

Solve this and you should have your code working.